# Откуда ошибка "warning: implicit declaration of function xxx"?

Tags: c, c99

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void lol (void)
{
    printf("356");
    hello();
    return;
}

void gutenTag (void)
{
    printf("Guten Tag!");
    return;
}

void hello (void)
{
    printf("Hello, world!");
    gutenTag();
    return;
}

void main (void)  
{
    hello();
    lol();
    lol();
    hello();
    return; 
}
```

**c99**

**console.txt**

```
C:\c>gcc hello2.c -o hello2.exe

hello2.c: In function 'lol':
hello2.c:7:2: warning: implicit declaration of function 'hello' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
hello();
^
hello2.c: At top level:
hello2.c:20:6: warning: conflicting types for 'hello'
void hello (void)
  ^
hello2.c:7:2: note: previous implicit declaration of 'hello' was here
hello();
^
`
```

Comment: в `lol` юзаешь `hello` до ее объявления

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы `hello()` в `lol()` использовали *до* объявления.

Или расположите их в порядке `gutenTag-hello-lol`, или до `lol` объявите

```
void hello();
```

Comment: Тогда уж лучше `void hello(void)` - если делать объявление, то с *прототипом*. Это не говоря уже о том, что непрототипные объявления функций являются в С *obsolescent feature*.

Answer (score 5):

До стандарта c99 разрешалось использовать (вызывать) функции без явного предварительного их объявления. В таких случаях, наличие вызова подобной функции `f()` в коде воспринималось компилятором так же, как если бы ранее точки использования было бы объявление вида:

```
int f();
```

Т.е. предполагается функция, возвращающая `int` и принимающая ещё неизвестное, но фиксированное кол-во аргументов. И, например, такой код:

```
int main(void) {
    f(1, 2);
    return 0;
}

int f(int a, int b) { return 0; }
```

является вполне валидным для c89. Но в c99 эту лавочку прикрыли, и следующие строгим стандартам компиляторы должны подобный код запрещать. Однако для совместимости часто ограничиваются предупреждениями (в Вашем случае как раз предупреждение, а не ошибка). Для исключения таких проблем нужно добавить предварительное объявление функции перед её вызовом (или просто перенести всю реализацию выше).

Comment: А `extern`-то тут причем? Почему не просто `int f();`? Код же вашего примера не содержит constraint violations, но тем не менее порождает неопределенное поведение, которое может выражаться и в отказе компилятора компилировать код. Считать ли код с UB "валидным" - вопрос отдельный.

Comment: @AnT `extern` для функций не обязателен, но он ничего и не портит. Про кол-во параметров учёл. Насчёт *constraint violations* хотел бы услышать пояснение.

Comment: "Constraint violation" - это повод для "ошибки компиляции".